# Best laptop for ubuntu and VisualStudio

Tags: laptop, virtualbox, configuration, vmware, virtualization

I am unsatisfied windows user moved to Ubuntu. I like ubuntu a lot and at the same time I am a .net developer who needs to use Visual Studio and a couple of windows coupled applications like itunes.
Can some one suggest a good laptop?

Thank in advance.

Comment: please clarify your question,
installing ubuntu inside windows ,installing windows inside ubuntu or dual boot?

Comment: Question should probably be closed as AskUbuntu is not a place for shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System76](https://www.system76.com/) and [ZaReason](http://zareason.com/shop/home.php) make laptops exclusively for Ubuntu.